# Python pandas dataframe to list by column instead of row

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I would like to know if there is an easy way to convert pandas dataframe to list by column instead of row ? for the example below, can we have [['Apple','Orange','Kiwi','Mango'],[220,200,1000,800],['a','o','k','m']] ?

Appreciate if anyone can advise on this. Thanks

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Brand': ['Apple','Orange','Kiwi','Mango'],
        'Price': [220,200,1000,800],
        'Type' : ['a','o','k','m']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Brand', 'Price', 'Type'])

df.head()

df.values.tolist()
#[['Apple', 220, 'a'], ['Orange', 200, 'o'], ['Kiwi', 1000, 'k'], ['Mango', 800, 'm']]

#Anyway to have ?????
#[['Apple','Orange','Kiwi','Mango'],[220,200,1000,800],['a','o','k','m']]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use Transpose(T) attribute:

```
lst=df.T.values.tolist()
```

**OR**

use `transpose()` method:

```
lst=df.transpose().values.tolist()
```

If you print `lst` you will get:

```
[['Apple', 'Orange', 'Kiwi', 'Mango'], [220, 200, 1000, 800], ['a', 'o', 'k', 'm']]
```